# Using two PIP packages together that use event loops

Tags: python, pip, python-asyncio, uvloop

I'm trying to combine a Twitch API package (twitchio) with a webserver (sanic) with the intent of serving chat commands to a game running locally to the python script. I don't have to use Sanic or twitchio but those are the best results I've found for my project.

I *think* I understand why what I have so far isn't working but I'm at a total loss of how to resolve the problem. Most of the answers I've found so far deal with scripts you've written to use asyncio and not packages that make use of event loops.

I can only get the webserver OR the chat bot to function. I can't get them to both run concurrently.

This is my first attempt at using Python so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

from twitchio.ext import commands
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic(name='localserver')

bot = commands.Bot(
    token=os.environ['TMI_TOKEN'],
    client_id=os.environ['CLIENT_ID'],
    nick=os.environ['BOT_NICK'],
    prefix=os.environ['BOT_PREFIX'],
    initial_channels=[os.environ['CHANNEL']]
)

@app.route("/")
async def query(request):
    return json(comcache)

@bot.event
async def event_ready():
    'Called once when the bot goes online.'
    print(f"{os.environ['BOT_NICK']} is online!")
    ws = bot._ws  # this is only needed to send messages within event_ready
    await ws.send_privmsg(os.environ['CHANNEL'], f"/me has landed!")

@bot.event
async def event_message(ctx):
    'Runs every time a message is sent in chat.'
    # make sure the bot ignores itself and the streamer
    if ctx.author.name.lower() == os.environ['BOT_NICK'].lower():
        return
    await bot.handle_commands(ctx)
    # await ctx.channel.send(ctx.content)
    if 'hello' in ctx.content.lower():
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Hi, @{ctx.author.name}!")

@bot.command(name='test')
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test passed!')
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
    bot.run()
```